Flutter Run Failed After Updating Android Studio
After i update android studio i got an error when runnig my fluter ptoject
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform x86_debug-1.0.0-a18df97ca57a249df5d8d68cd0820600223ce262.jar (io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-a18df97ca57a249df5d8d68cd0820600223ce262) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Could not download x86_debug-1.0.0-a18df97ca57a249df5d8d68cd0820600223ce262.jar (io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-a18df97ca57a249df5d8d68cd0820600223ce262)
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-a18df97ca57a249df5d8d68cd0820600223ce262/x86_debug-1.0.0-a18df97ca57a249df5d8d68cd0820600223ce262.jar'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-a18df97ca57a249df5d8d68cd0820600223ce262/x86_debug-1.0.0-a18df97ca57a249df5d8d68cd0820600223ce262.jar'.
               > Read timed out

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 2m 19s


Delete build folder of flutter project and try again.

This is a general solution for this type of errors that have appeared with recent android studio and flutter updates.
Modify android>settings.gradle file with this;

id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false

Modify android>gradle>gradle-wrapper.properties file with this;

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-all.zip

